# Specify which version of Python runs in Automator?

Tags: python, macos, updates, automator

In my terminal and in CodeRunner my Python is updated to 2.7.6 but when I ran a shell script in the OSX Automator I found that it is running 2.7.2

How can I update the Automator Python to 2.7.6 like the rest of my compilers ?

Comment: Are you by chance using `#!/usr/bin/python` in your Automator script? That will run the system Python, which is 2.7.2 for Mt Lion. You need to point it to the correct location of your 2.7.6 binary

Comment: Instead of `#!/usr/bin/python`, put `#!/path/to/2/7/6/python` - if you're using the Python.org installation, it's likely `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` or something along those lines. You'll need to determine exactly what it is for your system. If you can run `python` from the command line and get the right version, enter `which python` and it'll give you the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't specify explicitly which python for it to use.
So, I ran it in `bash` environment with following command:

`$ your/python/path /path/to/your/python/script.py`

And make sure first line of your python program contains the path to the python environment you wish to use. 
Eg:

`#! /usr/local/bin/python`