# Installing pip with default python on Mac OS 10.14 Mojave

Tags: python, macos, pip

I would like to install pip for the default installation of Python on Mac OS.

*Please don't recommend brew, I already have it and installed Python 3 with it, but it seems that Automator only knows how to use the default version of Python located in /usr/bin/python That's the reason behind my specific request*

I did my homework first, or tried to, before asking the question, but what I found confusing is that the recommended method seems to be using get-pip.py, but the pip documentation says

> **Warning Be cautious if you are using a Python install that is managed
> by your operating system or another package manager. get-pip.py does
> not coordinate with those tools, and may leave your system in an
> inconsistent state.**

This threw me off, as I don't want to risk breaking the default Python on Mac OS, as I understood that might mess my system.

I also didn't want to use the deprecated easy_install.

And I couldn't find an answer to my question, as usually the answers just recommend installing a different version of Python with brew.

Comment: Are you calling a Python script with Automator? Does it start with a shebang?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I was trying to get the script to work IN Automator, not call it from bash/AppleScript. Didn't work, so I am now calling it from bash, and since I am doing so, I am running it with python3. Passing on the arguments was the biggest hurdle, as they are folder paths and some contain spaces. Yes, the script itself starts with a shebang.

Answer (score 1):

> Please don't recommend brew, I already have it and installed Python 3 with it, but it seems that Automator only knows how to use the default version of Python located in /usr/bin/python That's the reason behind my specific request

Can you possibly use "Run Shell Script" in Automator and specify the python version you want to use. See [Specify which version of Python runs in Automator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505085/specify-which-version-of-python-runs-in-automator) and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/233890/calling-python-3-script-from-applescript

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up doing, except I called the python script from bash. Thought about it before, but had some trouble passing on the arguments. I use the Automator app by dragging a bunch of folders on it, and some paths might contain spaces, and that caused some issues, but I finally managed to pass them on to python. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Seems like Automator isn’t loading /usr/local/Cellar/bin into your PATH. You can echo $PATH in Automator to confirm this.

## Solution

Reinstall using brew and ensure that you run brew link python.

You can export `PATH=...` before running your script **or** move `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/pythonx.x` where x is the default version installed, then symlink `/usr/bin/python` to your brew installed python in `/usr/local/bin/`.