# python script ImportError: No module named 'webbot' when running shell script in Automator

Tags: python, shell, python-3.6, automator

I have a shell script action that has the following command:

`python /Users/my_name/Desktop/webbot/do_something.py`

but I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/my_name/Desktop/webbot/do_something.py", line 1, in <module> from webbot import Browser  ImportError: No module named webbot`

I've ran this python script manually and it works fine, but in Automator I keep hitting this error. Both pip and python versions are 3.6.

**Edit:**

The python script

[image: python script]

The shell script + traceback of error message
[image: shell script + traceback of error message]

I have checked where pip installs my packages and webbot is with all the other ones. I tried importing other packages in the python script and running it in Automator and packages like matplotlib work fine.

Comment: The python script which works fine manually, is that running on Virtual Environment ?

Comment: No it’s just on my local machine.

Comment: Well, i could not reproduce this issue here. Its working fine. You need to give more information. Like share your `python script` and `shell script`

Comment: `pip install webbot`?

Comment: Yes that's what I used to install it in my terminal and is why it works when I run it manually from a terminal tab. But running it through Automator seems to be different. Even running `pip install webbot` in the shell script within Automator throws an error stating: `command not found: pip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Automator doesn't use python 3.6 by default and therefore it wasn't able to find the modules pip installed in the 3.6 folder. Following this link's answer [Specify which version of Python runs in Automator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505085/specify-which-version-of-python-runs-in-automator) it shows how you specify to Automator which python version to use before then running the python script.